# Formatação Data

Tags: laravel

Bom dia, alguém poderia me ajudar nessa formatação? Bom, tenho o seguinte formulário:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">        
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 form-label">
        {{Form::label('date', 'Data')}}
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-10 col-xs-10">            
        {{Form::date('date', null, ['class' => 'form-control'])}}
    </div>     
</div>
```

Tenho uma query com um select pegando o campo data:

```
$query = DB::table('empenho as emp')
            ->select('emp.date as a')->orderby('emp.nrEmpenho');
```

Então eu valido as informações do meu formulário:

```
if ($request->date) $query->where('emp.date', $request->date);
```

Tudo funciona perfeitamente, mas ele me retorna o campo nesse formato:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu gostaria que me retornasse o campo em Dia/Mes/Ano, achei que usando o Carbon::parse na model resolveria, mas não resolveu, tentei fazer assim na minha model Empenho:

```
<?php

namespace Portal\Entity\Contabilidade;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class Empenho extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'empenho';
    public $timestamps = false;
    public static $snakeAttributes = false;
    protected $dates = ['date'];

public function getdateAttribute($value)
    {
        return Carbon::parse($value)->format('d/m/Y');
    }
}
```

Não funciona e eu não sei o que fazer, alguém poderia me ajudar por favor? Qualquer coisa que não estiver clara no código me informe que eu posto qualquer outra informação necessária, obrigado !

Comment: Só `$value->format('d/m/Y');` não funciona?

Comment: Na verdade só funciona pra um select em um formulário, quando se clica na caixa ele mostra a seleção formatada, mas no resultado o formato volta à forma do banco de dados. :/

Comment: Se vc mudar o tipo de input para `text` o resultado é o mesmo?

Comment: Mas você misturou as coisas, isso não vai funcionar! A definição está no model, mas o select você está usando `DB::table('tabela')`. Até onde eu sei, isso não certo.

Comment: Wallace, eu uso Carbon e formato o campo na model mesmo ! Até o formulário tudo funciona perfeitamente, já no filtro volta ao formato normal.

Comment: Qual versão do Laravel?

Comment: 5.1 ----  O amigo lá em baixo me ajudou, obrigado pelas respostas !

Comment: Ajudou mas não é a melhor forma

Comment: Verdade, é vista com "gambiarra" né, me informaram, mais ao menos funcionou, se você souber alguma forma bem vista poderia me informar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente usar o `DATE_FORMAT(campo, 'formato')` do mysql, e use o método estático `DB::raw()` (sql cru), para permitir a formatação:

```
$query = DB::table('empenho as emp')
            ->select(DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(emp.date, "%Y-%m-%d") as a'))->orderby('emp.nrEmpenho');
```

Comment: Cara, achei impossível isso não funcionar, mas não funcionou, deu erro, diz que a coluna é desconhecida na lista de campos, eu formatei o código para não ficar muito grande o post, me pergunto se é por causa que meu select está buscando outras informações fora o campo date, que deve ser improvável também, estou aprendendo agora, por favor, me ajude.

Comment: Tenta denovo, editei a resposta, é coisa do laravel.

Comment: Você é o cara, muito obrigado, sou novato no fórum e não consigo te reputar, mesmo assim fica aqui meus mais sinceros agradecimentos, muito obrigado mesmo, Deus lhe abençoe !  <--Problema totalmente resolvido-->

Comment: Se serviu, é só clicar na setinha  abaixo do número, obrigado.